# Backgrounds for UInavigationBar and UIPickerView

Tags: cocoa-touch

I understand that when you create a navigation controller it comes with a navigation bar, you are only able to select three backgrounds for this (example: translucent black etc). I've seen applications that have other colors like green with the "translucent black" type feature. Are they simply creating their own background view's and setting it for the UINavigationBar? how do they get this "translucent" effect too? like the whole view is not a single color, but the top is like a lilttle transparent and the bottom a different color. Similar to the UIPickerView that has a nice design in the background.

How can I do this? design the graphs with a graphic design program? or simply use quartz (gradients, etc) on views to get this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can change the color by changing the [tintColor](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/tintColor) property of the UINavigationBar

```
myBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: Didn't see this property before! Thanks.

What about the background of UIPickerView?

Comment: Not sure about UIPickerView, it would probably require custom subviews or background views, I didn't find any helper functions for it.

Comment: Probably. If you can link to a screenshot, then it'll be easier to determine.