# change the color of the Navigation item

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uinavigationitem

i am using SplitView Controller in my app.there is a Run options navigation item in my Split view.i cant able to change the color of the Navigation item.

how can i do this.can any one tell me a good way to do it?

Comment: Are you talking about the bar button or the navigation bar?

Answer (score 3):

Try this on out,

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

[see also this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387883/backgrounds-for-uinavigationbar-and-uipickerview)

Comment: Or: `self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];`